# How to specify a foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, foreign-keys

i.e. Post model has a column poster_id and for posters I'm actually using User model. Obviously this is a User has_many Posts relationship, but how to I specify that poster_id is actually an id to User model?

Comment: Everything you want and more is in here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use foreign_key option:

```
has_many :posts, :foreign_key => :poster_id
```

For Post model it will be

```
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => :poster_id
```

or

```
belongs_to :poster, :class_name => 'User'
```